# Jquery and Semantic-ui combine these two

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Sorry for my ignorance but I am getting some dynamic content on the page and need the semantic popup to work.
How do I do that?
I basically need to merge these:

```
$('body').on('click', '.fakelink', function() {

});

    $('.fakelink').popup({
    on: 'hover'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.fakelink', function() {
   $(this).popup({
      on: 'hover'
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.fakelink', function() {
    $(this).popup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('body').on('mouseover', '.fakelink', function() {
    $(this).popup({
        on: 'click',
        content  : 'My favorite dog would like other dogs as much as themselves'
    });
});
```

});

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mike_123/55pta4tz/)